# Voltage increase by connecting Voltmeter

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

[image]

I've got this scheme. V1 and V2 are voltmeters without their own power supply. (V1 gets power from the measured circuit, V2 is powered separately, but in this case from the same power supply.)

The power supply is two batteries connected in series.

- V1 alone (V2 disconnected) shows 7.7 V.
- V2 alone (V1 disconnected) shows 6.9 V.
- V1 and V2 (both connected) show V1=5.8V, V2=7.4V

What made me to ask this question is:

V2 alone shows 6.9 V. When V1 gets connected the V2 shows 7.4 V (voltage increases).

Baterries should be almost full, checked with another (independent) Voltmeter, with its own power supply, Both show ~4.6V.

Both Voltmeters had been ordered long time ago on ebay - no data sheets, no information. Picture of the back side of one of them:
[image]

The main point of the question:
How can voltage increase in the same measured spot, if you connect one more load (voltmeter)?

Comment: There must be something important about your meters that you haven't told us. Please provide links to datasheets for both meters. Also, be careful when providing voltage measurements to tell us **which** meter you are reading.

Comment: There exists a 1.5 to 2 volt drop from nominal somewhere in there. Are you experimenting with discharged or partially charged batteries? You should disconnect the batteries completely and measure their actual terminal voltages. Discharged batteries behave differently. Also, it would be interesting to know what both readings are when they are both connected - sometimes meters just aren't in agreement about a given value.

Comment: Updated the question!

Comment: Those readings are... strange. That's almost like voltage divider behavior. Did you perhaps attach an earth ground somewhere to this circuit? Even if you didn't, the voltages being that far out of agreement points to them being calibrated very differently, or else they aren't measuring the same electrical quantity for some reason. You may want to use your other voltmeter to get readings on those same points with the whole thing assembled.